# Direct method from SQL command text to DataSet

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

What is the most direct route to get a DataSet if I have a sql command?

```
string sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
string connectionString = "blahblah";

DataSet = GetDataSet(sqlCommand,connectionString);

GetDataSet()
{
   //...?
}
```

I started with `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`, but the closest thing I see in the API is `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`.  With this method, I'll need to get a `SqlDataReader` and then convert this to a `DataSet` manually.  I figure there is a more direct route to accomplish the task.

If easier, a `DataTable` will also fit my goal.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
public DataSet GetDataSet(string ConnectionString, string SQL)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = SQL;
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    ///conn.Open();
    da.Fill(ds);
    ///conn.Close();

    return ds;
}
```

Answer (score 30):

Just finish it up.

```
string sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
string connectionString = "blahblah";

DataSet ds = GetDataSet(sqlCommand, connectionString);
```

```
DataSet GetDataSet(string sqlCommand, string connectionString)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
        sqlCommand, new SqlConnection(connectionString)))
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        ds.Tables.Add(table);
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: Odd. I've been having a SQL problem recently and DataSet.Fill has been returning no records. table.Load however does return records. Thanks for sharing this method - wish I knew why I was having problems.

Comment: If you were referring to Adrian's code, it uses the **DataAdapter** to fill (i.e. `da` and not `ds` - the two variable names are similar).

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Any idea why using the DataAdapter to fill returns null, but using table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader()) returns a row?

Comment: I was thinking you may have accidentally typed in `ds.Fill` instead of `da.Fill`.

Comment: Ah no, I wish that was it :).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'm wondering, why you dont close the connection ?

Comment: The `using` statement calls `try...finalize` under the hood, and the `finalize` statement is supposed to close all connections and dispose of all memory references (note that Microsoft Access does NOT do this!).

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string textDataSource = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TEST_C;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd";

public static DataSet LoaderDataSet(string StrSql)      
{
    SqlConnection cnn;            
    SqlDataAdapter dad;
    DataSet dts = new DataSet();
    cnn = new SqlConnection(textDataSource);
    dad = new SqlDataAdapter(StrSql, cnn);
    try
    {
        cnn.Open();
        dad.Fill(dts);
        cnn.Close();

        return dts;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        return dts;
    }
    finally
    {
        dad.Dispose();
        dts = null;
        cnn = null;
    }
}
```