# Obtaining a dataset from a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am a newbie to C# and I need to obtain a dataset from a dummy database I have made. I'm used to coding in objective-c and using php/mysql to deal with the data insertion/extraction....

Can anyone tell me how to obtain an entire table of data from a SQL Server database? Or at least point me in the direction of a reliable defacto source?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use provider for MSSQL - [SqlDataAdapter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
string CnStr=@"put_here_connection_string";
SqlDataAdapter adp=new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tableName",CnStr);
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds,"TableName");
```

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of ways to do this; look at tutorials like:

[Introduction to SqlClient](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlclient)

A typical code example to just return a data table might look like:

```
public static DataTable GetTable(string tableName, string connectionString)
{

  using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(tableName))
    {
      myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
      myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
      using (SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
      {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Load(reader);
        return table;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Note the use of the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) keyword. This will ensure your connection is disposed when you are finished with it.

There's example code for obtaining a DataSet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584817/direct-method-from-sql-command-text-to-dataset).

You can also vary how you execute your command; you can use `myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text` and set the CommandString to `"SELECT * FROM myTable"`. You can also use `CommandType.StoredProcedure` and use the name of a stored procedure.

You might also want to look at abstracting all of this away using one of the many solutions available. Microsoft have the [Application Data blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648460.aspx), [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx), and there are plenty of other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

Here is a video what you are looking for but not up to date:
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-data-driven-web-sites

maybe you should check out the getting started section:
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos

Another choice would be ASP.NET MVC if you have some MVC insides (Rails, PHP, etc)
http://www.asp.net/mvc

This is a complete walk through application:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store

I would recommend looking at mvc and the music store example
HTH

Answer (score -1):

See this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION_STRING"))
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("TbaleName", conn)
                                { CommandType = CommandType.Table };
    adapter.Fill(dataset);
    return dataset;
}
```

To know more about what to write in `CONNECTION_STRING` [see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: hmm, when adding my table name is throws an exception saying that it requires a stored procedure...

Comment: You need to set the command type on the SelectCommand to be CommandType.Table