# cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'system.data.dataset'

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

Hi all, please I need your help, I am trying to execute a query and put all the retrieved data in a data set, but I get this error `"cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'system.data.dataset'"`

Here's the code:

```
// this is a small piece of the sql
 String Astra_conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AstraSeverConnection"].ConnectionString;

System.Text.StringBuilder sql = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

sql.Append(" SELECT ROWNUM AS ID, institution, LPAD (a.zone_name, 3, '0') AS campus, ");
sql.Append(" term_name AS term, student_instance_id AS student_id, subject, course, ");
sql.Append(" section_name AS section_num, offering AS title, ");

//Its OracleConnection because it is an Oracle server otherwise, it would be SqlConnection.

    DataSet rs = new DataSet();
    OracleConnection Astra_db_Conn = new OracleConnection(Astra_conn);
    string myquery = sql.ToString();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(myquery);

Astra_db_Conn.Open();
try
{
    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter();
    rs = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // this is where is get the error.
    adpt.Fill(rs);

}
catch(Exception e) 
{
log.Error(&quot;*** ERROR *** IRISExportQueries.loadStudentInfoLearningSites():&quot; + e);

}
```

I've also tried

```
 Astra_db_Conn.Open();
 try
 {
     SqlDataReader reader = new SqlDataAdapter();
     reader = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // this is where is get the error.


 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
log.Error(&amp;quot;*** ERROR *** IRISExportQueries.loadStudentInfoLearningSites():&amp;quot; + e);&lt;/pre&gt;

 }
```

Then I get the error: `"cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader'"`

Thanks your help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of affected rows (an integer) and not a `DataSet` or `DataReader`. I'm afraid you're not using ADO.NET components correctly.

These 2 lines are enough to fill a DataSet

```
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adpt.Fill(rs);
```

In any case this is not your only problem, you're mixing `Sql*` ADO.NET components with `Oracle*`ones. Adapter should be `OracleDataAdapter`

```
OracleDataAdapter adpt = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
adpt.Fill(rs);
```

Something else: you're never assigning the connection to the command. You should do

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(myquery, Astra_db_Conn);
```

And at last but not least important, dispose every instance of classes implementing `IDisposable` interface, otherwise unmanaged resources as connections to datasase won't be released.

This is the final version applying all my suggestions

```
var rs = new DataSet();
string myquery = sql.ToString();
using (var Astra_db_Conn = new OracleConnection(Astra_conn))
using (var cmd = new OracleCommand(myquery, Astra_db_Conn))
using (var adpt = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    Astra_db_Conn.Open();
    adpt.Fill(rs);
}
```

Comment: I can tell you've been in the business for a long time, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The method [ExecuteNonQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) returns an int with the number of rows that are affected by the command.

To access the data from the query you should see this existing answer: [Direct method from SQL command text to DataSet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6584858/2579950).

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlDataAdapter adapt= new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText,cmd.Connection);
adapt.Fill(rs, " Your Table name as it is in database inside this quotation");
```

now u can give source to ur data views like datalist or datatable or gridview as following

```
Datalist1.DataSource= rs.Tables("Your Table name as it is in database inside the above q mark")
```

now atlast jst bind it

```
Datalist1.DataBind();
```