# The best method for filling a datagrid in c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagrid, devexpress

I want to make a SELECT over a few tables from a ms sql server,
(only a select, no updates, inserts oder deletes),
and generate a (groupable devexpress) datagrid from the results.

Which method is
b) or the fastest (regarding the response time)
c) or the one with the fewest code?

Using
- an automatically created dataset
- a manually created dataset from the select
(like [Direct method from SQL command text to DataSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584817/direct-method-from-sql-command-text-to-dataset))
- Linq to SQL
- or another method?

What method do you prefer?

I ́m looking forward to your answers.

Best regards

Frank

Comment: Direct method from SQL command text to DataSet

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way with **few code** would be to **load** the data **into** a **datatable** and then bind the data as **datasource to a datagridview**. Notice that this example does not handle any **sql injection** issues.

*Load data into datatable:*

```
  public static DataTable SelectData(string sCommand)
  {
          DataTable dtData = null;
          try
          {
            dtData = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("your connection string goes here"))
            {
              using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sCommand, connection))
              {
                connection.Open();
                da.Fill(dtData);
              }
            }                    
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
          }         
          return dtData;
   }
```

*Bind the table to datagridview:*

```
DataTable dtData = SelectData("SELECT * FROM mytable");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtData;
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastes way will be the DataTable as Koryu described. I my opinion is it much more beautiful to make a class which holds the Attributes from you Select as Property.

For example:

```
SELECT cId, name, email from customer
```

for this you would build a class:

```
public class Customer{

    public Customer(int id, string name, string email){
    this.Id = id;
    this.Name = name;
    this.Email = email;
    }

    public int Id {get; private set;}
    public string Name {get; private set;}
    public string Email{get; private set;}

    public static IEnumerable<Customer> ReadCustomer(){

           //Here you read the data from database and add each row to you List of Customer.
    }
}
```

So you can define your List of Customer as DataSource for the grid.

```
myGrid.DataSource = Customer.ReadCustomer();
```

If you are using a BindingList as DataSource you can directly work with the NewItemRow which allows the enduser to directly create new Objects from Customer to the DataSource.

I think this is good way to handle.