# FillDataSet is not declared msg

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Function GetCategories() As DataSet

  Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM Categories"
  Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query)
  Return FillDataSet(cmd, "Categories")

 End Function
```

Comment: This isn't a Visual Studio question. Please tag properly.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you haven't actually defined the `FillDataSet` method.

I think you may have meant to use the `SqlDataAdapter`'s `Fill` method. You can see a complete example of how to do that here: [Direct method from SQL command text to DataSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584817/direct-method-from-sql-command-text-to-dataset)